# Time difference while calling springboot rest API

Tags: spring-boot, oracle12c, timezone-offset

I am getting one hour difference between the time stored in database table and a rest GET call. I am not sure why this is happening as my database, rest server and UI application runs on same timezone. Please help me with this.

```
Time stored in database : 2020-05-19
Time on REST GET call   : 2020-05-18T23:00:00.000+0000
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where you get the Date?

Comment: @SimonMartinelliv It is a find by id call on an entity. The date is a field of that entity.

Comment: Please show code. Is it a Date or a LocalDate?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it is Date from java.util.Date package

Comment: Where do you see the time on the REST Call? How do you call the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault();` to check java sever default timeZone another issue maybe with hibernate reading from mysql/postgre they depend on default calendar while `prepare-statement()` if not calendar been passed for them. Default means UTC.

Few points to consider here:

- **Always save as UTC in database**: in some cases you want to move your server to different timezone you don't want your records to get effected.
- Make sure to **convert date & data/time to String before sending/receiving data** from any APIs call. Unless, Time-conversion is required (ex: Promotion applied from 12:00 AM to 6:00 AM in each country)

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateUtil {
    public static final String dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm";

    public static Date getDate(String date) {
        return getDate(date, dateFormat);
    }

    public static Date getDate(String date, String stringFormat) {
        if (date == null || date.length() == 0)
            return null;

        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat(stringFormat).parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String getDateFormatted(Date date) {
        return DateUtil.getDateFormatted(date, dateFormat);
    }

    public static String getDateFormatted(Date date, String stringFormat) {
        if (date == null)
            return "";

        return new SimpleDateFormat(stringFormat).format(date);
    }
}


public class UserBean {
    @JsonIgnore // Just to ignore sending to API
    private Date lastLogInDate;

    private String lastLogInDateFormatted;

    public Date getLastLogInDate() {
      return lastLogInDate;
    }

    // Auto create the String formatted verion of the date on setter
    public void setLastLogInDate(Date lastLogInDate) {
      this.lastLogInDate = lastLogInDate;
      this.lastLogInDateFormatted = DateUtil.getDateFormatted(lastLogInDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
    }

    public String getLastLogInDateFormatted() {
      return lastLogInDateFormatted;
    }

    public void setLastLogInDateFormatted(String lastLogInDateFormatted) {
      this.lastLogInDateFormatted = lastLogInDateFormatted;
    }
}

// Receive params from API
public class OrderParam {
      public String orderDate;
    // ...
    // ...
}

// Convert String Date to java.util.Date
public class OrderService {
      public void processOrder(OrderParam param) {
        Date orderDate = DateUtil.getDate(param.orderDate);
        // .....
        // ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I think even though your server and UI runs on same timezone. Sometimes the code itself might be getting time from different timezone such as database timezone. Use calendar to get and store the time. Calendar uses the timezone of them server. Make sure to make attribute as where you use to store the date as **String** type.

Comment: Calendar? Since Java 8 we have a DateTime API